# Can flatulence be a cause of sleeplessness?

Tags: sleep-deprivation, cause-and-effect, flatulence-gas-fart, insomnia, drowsy

Traditional knowledge about heath in my country is guided by Ayurveda and according to it sleeplessness can be [a symptom](http://www.chandigarhayurvedcentre.com/herbal-remedies-for-flatulence/) of flatulence. I wonder if a connection between flatulence and sleeplessness exists and has been discovered by modern medicine.

**Research:**

I found only [freemd.com](http://www.freemd.com/s2/2228/bad-insomnia-flatulence.htm) of DSHI Systems correlate [Flatulence with insomnia](http://www.freemd.com/s2/2228/bad-insomnia-flatulence.htm).

Comment: Since starting Pentasa tablets (anti-inflammatory drug for ulcerative colitis which causes flatulence) my insomnia has markedly diminished. I hope this improvement keeps up.

Answer (score 3):

Flatulence, which is likely associated with abdominal distention and thus some discomfort, can disturb sleep.

Sources:

- Functional Abdominal Bloating with Distention ([ISRN Obstetrics and Gynecology, 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3388350/))
- Tips for a Quiet Tummy, Restful Sleep ([WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/indigestion-sleep#1))